# Change .NET Core application generated exe description

Tags: .net-core, csproj

I have created a .NET Core application. When I do:

`dotnet publish -r win81-x64`

All files needed to execution are deployed in the following folder:

`\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\win81-x64\publish`

There, among all the files I have a dll file with the name Example.dll and the exe file named Example.exe. Now, my problem is when I execute the exe, in the task manager the application description says:

> dotnet

I would like to change that to Example, for that I tried to edit my csproj to contain the following:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
    <Description>Example</Description>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win81-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <Satellite_Description>Example</Satellite_Description>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

But it doesn't seems to have any affect in the generated exe file, only ind the dll. How can I change the exe description?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently this is not possible in the build process.

Unlike classic .NET projects, this `.exe` file isn't actually compiled but is a pre-built binary (`dotnet.exe`, in 2.0 `apphost.exe`) acquired via a NuGet package and copied/renamed to the publish output.

There is an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup/issues/2007) about changing the description after being launched, but at the time of writing it is not assigned to a milestone of an expected release.

Answer (score 0):

There is known issue in populating assemblyino manifest into EXE file. Looks like will be supported in .net core 3.0 release.

see: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/1899